# My program crashes, I don't understand why it does not even reach the first printf

Tags: c, function

My program is supposed to order a list of numbers inputed by the user, but        it crashes even before reaching the first printf. My compiler makes 2 warnings, but I don't see the issue. I haven't studied pointers yet, so I didn't want to use them. Here are the messages:

In function `selection_sort':

```
[Warning] passing arg 2 of `selection_sort' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

In function `main':

```
[Warning] passing arg 2 of `selection_sort' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int selection_sort(int n, int v[n])
{
    int high = v[0];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        high = high < v[i]? v[i] : high;

    if(n - 1 == 0)
        return;

     v[n - 1] = high;
     n -= 1;

     selection_sort(n, v[n]);
}   



int main(void)
{   
    int n, i;
    int v[n];

    printf("Enter how many numbers are to be sorted: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter numbers to be sorted: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);

    selection_sort(n, v[n]);

    printf("In crescent order: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", v[i]);

    getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If you see `int v[n];`, what do you think it does?

Comment: Follow-up to @Gabe: Note that, at that point, n does not have a value.

Comment: I thought it declared an array. Is it wrong?

Comment: @user3091996: How big did you think that array would be?

Comment: `scanf` is an advanced topic, only suitable for use by persons with 10+ years experience using C.  Why do educators insist on trying to teach it before pointers, which are a fundamental concept that must be undestood to grasp the language.  Your misunderstanding of pointers and how they relate to arrays is directly related to the confusion you are having.

Comment: @WilliamPursell (totally right, not to mention that `scanf()` is an advanced topic not even of pointers - which are IMHO are quite basic stuff - but because of its little details and quirks which make its usage completely counter-intuitive.)

Comment: @user3091996 `int v[100]` declares `v` to be an array of 100 `int`s. You cannot declare an array to be `int v[n]` before having assigned a value to `n`, for the compiler will not know how much room to allocate to `v`. If you have not studied pointers yet, I recommend declaring `v` to be some static number like `int v[100]` and then refusing to allow the user to enter more than 100 numbers.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I declared v after n's input by the user, now the program reaches the second printf and probably scanf. But then it crashes. I'm not sure if by doing `n -= 1` I will reduce the array to be modified, does that work?

Comment: Compiler warnings are there for a reason, not just to annoy you.

Comment: @user3091996 You should read the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20525182/509868) by Dr. Tower: it points out the second bug in your code. Please try to fix it, and ask a different question if you don't manage.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I tried to compile it anyway because sometimes warnings are not necessarily mistakes.

Comment: @user3091996: If you are just starting out with C programming ALL warnings are mistakes. You don't know enough yet to know when to ignore warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `v`, not `v[n]` to the function selection_sort. `v` is the array, `v[n]` is actually an out of bounds element of `v`.

the line should be `selection_sort(n, v);`

Comment: Hi! That helped, but now it stores the highest value on all array's slots.

Comment: I'll try to fix it, if I'm not able I'll come back.

Answer (score 5):

Your program is using a variable length array, a feature that was added in C99.

However, you declare its size based on an uninitialized variable. What did you believe would happen there?

In C, variables declared inside functions are NOT set to 0. They are not set to anything. They pick up whatever value was left on the stack or in the register that they are assigned.

I believe that your program is crashing because `n` in `int v[n]` is a ridiculously big number and `v` is trying to use too much memory.

You can probably fix this by moving your array declaration below the `scanf` that reads in `n`.

Comment: Surely in C decallarations need ot be first - but can't you make a function and call that to initialise `n`?

Comment: @doctorlove: Didn't C99 change to make declarations work anywhere, like C++ does? If it didn't you can still do it by using a function, or you can just make a new block with { and }, and declare it at the top of the new block.

Comment: @ZanLynx no idea - I should probably practise some C99

Comment: @doctorlove: Me either. I use either C++ or C89, because Microsoft never updated to C99 and GCC defaults to C89.